# Need Help in  simultaneous operation on form submit

Tags: php, forms, paypal, submit

I have a page that submits data to PayPal, through their standard form fields.(not using their button generator)

Normally i would have the user fill out the form and then on submit go to the page that process the data to mysql and sets the new hidden form fields to be submitted to paypal.

I want to be able to insert the data into the database via php/mysql and pass the variables to PayPal with one submit button. Can I do that some how?

simultaneous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the instructions for  [Implementing the Simplest Express Checkout Integration](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECSimpleIntegration#id085LHM007Y4).

It is a little long but it explains exactly what you need to do.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Byron, I should have looked here first.